# Laravel object_get

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a base `User` model object. Each user can be either a staff member, parent or student. Each account type also has an associated model.

For example:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function details()
    {
        switch($this->account_type) {
            case 'staff':    return $this->hasOne(Staff::class);
            case 'student':  return $this->hasOne(Student::class);
            case 'parent':   return $this->hasOne(ParentUser::class);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

If I run:

```
 echo $user->details->staff_code;
```

Then it outputs `CRS` for example. However, if I run it with `object_get()`:

```
object_get($user, 'details.staff_code');
```

Then it outputs `null`.

I figured because in the `object_get()` method, it has this line:

```
if (! is_object($object) || ! isset($object->{$segment}))
```

I assume because the `details` property is a magic/dynamic laravel model property, `isset()` doesn't work on it.

Whats the best way to handle this? Is it safe to edit the `object_get()` method and replace the `isset()` segment with something more robust? I don't really want to edit source code in the Vendor directory.

Should I create my own `object_get` helper function, and if so, where should I place it / autoload it?

Is there another method of achieving the result I want that I'm unaware of?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems a bit hacky, but it seems to work, and I only need to do it on the one `User` model.

I've taken the magic `__isset()` method from the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, and overrode it in the `User` class.

I've also added a `method_exists` check in the `__isset()` method to check to see if the relationship method exists. Because if the relationship method exists, at least we know that the dynamic variable with the same method name exists.

This is the `__isset()` method in my model if anyone else needs it:

```
public function __isset($key)
{
    return (
                isset($this->attributes[$key]) || 
                isset($this->relations[$key]) || 
                method_exists(static::class, $key)
           ) ||
           ($this->hasGetMutator($key) && ! is_null($this->getAttributeValue($key)));
}
```

Now, if I run:

```
object_get($user, 'details.staff_code')
```

It returns the correct value, instead of the default `null`.